# What's the difference between "::" and "sys" schemas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

As far as I know, BOL exmaple on [`fn_trace_getinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173875.aspx) used to use 
 `::` instead of `sys` schema in the example like following

From

```
    SELECT * FROM ::fn_trace_getinfo(default)
```

To

```
    SELECT * FROM sys.fn_trace_getinfo(default)
```

**Are there any differences between those two?**
And **what does `::` mean?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, i hope [this](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/78872-udf-starting-fn_) (UDF starting with fn_...) helps

From the page it seems that :: would tell Sql Server that this has to be a System UDF, and will only be found in Master DB.

> Q:
>
> I've read frequently how stored
>   procedures we create shouldn't be
>   named with sp_ since SQL Server will
>   first check the master db before the
>   current db when trying to find the sp
>   to execute. I always nodded and
>   thought how I was glad I hadn't done
>   that. For some reason it never clicked
>   that UDF behavior could be the same.
>
> I have several UDFs that start fn_...
>   When I reference a UDF as dbo.fn_...
>   does SQL Server check the master db
>   for these and only upon not finding
>   them check the current db? If so, is
>   there a performance hit for this?
>
> A:
>
> No. To call a system-supplied UDF, you
>   need to use ::, so that is what SQL
>   Server looks for. All system-supplied
>   UDFs are table functions, as scalar
>   system functions are not UDFs at all.

Answer (score 2):

[Even the SQL Experts are not sure. It changed from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2005](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2006/09/06/186.aspx)

My random guess is the [user/schema separation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx) in SQL Server 2005 removed the need for a shorthand system schema